# No endpoint entry found when load balancing IdentityServer4

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx, https, load-balancing, identityserver4

I am attempting to setup a local nginx load balanced IDS (using a hybrid model, and HTTPS), using docker containers.

I can successfully login if I scale the IDS to 1.

When I scale to 2 or more, using round robin style balancing, I am redirected to the login page when I attemp to login.

The initial login attempt hits IDS1, then the second request portion of the login hits IDS2, which returns the following error: **No endpoint entry found for request path: /Account/Login [IdentityServer4.Hosting.EndpointRouter]**

I have verified both IDS's are up and running, and if i hit the discovery document, I can see nginx round robining it and i get a successful result each time.

EDIT: I no longer get the error, but when I attempt to login the second request portion of the login going to IDS2 still acts as though I'm not mid-login process and takes me to the login page.

Comment: A bit unrelated but do you have the same DataProtection keys and signing keys in both services?

Comment: @ToreNestenius So an update to the issue, that error doesn't happen anymore (I changed the order of app.UseIdentityServer() in the configure in startup. But the real issue behind it is still happening (IDS2 thinks you aren't logged in at all and redirects back to login).

Comment: @ToreNestenius As for your question on DataProtection keys, I am currently only using IdentityServer.AddSignedCredential(certificate) to add an X509Certificate2, I do not use .AddDataProtection() currently.

Comment: Hope my answer below is an acceptable answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure The Data Protection API and set the same key in both services, because otherwise ASP.NET won't accept cookies from the other service. The key is used to secure and encrypt the cookie.

To lean about about the data protection API I recently wrote this reference project

- [AzureKeyVaultKeyRingRepository](https://github.com/edumentab/AzureKeyVaultKeyRingRepository)
  The purpose is to demonstrate and show how to store the ASP.NET Core Data Protection API key-ring in Azure Key Vault. (Blogpost coming soon)

Read more about the data protection API [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction)

Comment: I had to adjust to use local file system instead of Azure, but the concept worked great and solved my problem! thank you.

Comment: Glad you fixed it!